# Why am I getting a 500 internal server error with admin-ajax.php

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have multiple plugins that perform an ajax call, they run fine. However, the one I'm working on gives a "500 (internal server error)" on admin-ajax.php.

jquery:

```
$.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl,{action: 'my_action',animal:animalInfo},function(data){
            .....
        },'json');
```

php:

```
wp_enqueue_script('Namejs_user',plugins_url('/js/Namejs_user.js', __FILE__),'','',true);
        wp_localize_script( 'Namejs_user', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
```

I've changed variable names and I'm using "..." so I don't bore you with what I'm doing with the data but this is basically what's going on. Everytime the ajax call runs I get the 500 error.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should look at the webserver logs to see what's really causing the 500 error.

Comment: Just requested them. Hopefully, it'll give me some insight. Odd that the other ajax based plugin works though.

Comment: apache error.log could tell why error 500

Comment: The fact that it's ajax is irrelevant, the http request to the server produced a server error, which is why you're getting a 500 error.

Comment: after looking at the logs is turns out "http_parse_message()" is undefined since the pecl_http extension isn't installed.